# Is the negation "if not that, then something" correct?

Tags: phrases

As in the question, if I answer someone for example "if not that coat, then I'd not recognize you" is that correct? I understand that there are other forms like "if it wasn't for that coat...", just wondering about this one specific form.

Comment: It doesn't sound idiomatic to me - unless perhaps, in the context, there had been previous discussion  about the person's identification with that particular coat.

Comment: I'm sure you can find examples of similar constructions, but as WS2 says it's not idiomatic. It's more usual to have "if not..." modify or contrast with a noun phrase. "if not fashionable, at least **it** was warm." "If not chips, I want **something** to eat."

Comment: As a deletion, it would work in a licensing framework. "If I were wearing a coat over my Eton blazer – and I've plenty of coats besides this one – do you think you could still recognise me?" But then most strings can be made to work, at least to someone's satisfaction.

Comment: In some contexts a native speaker *might* say ***If not for** that coat, I wouldn't have recognised you*. But it's syntactically highly questionable, and most people would include a standard "subjunctive" construction there anyway: ***If it weren't / wasn't for for** that coat...* (or ***If it hadn't been for** that coat...*).

Comment: ...but a perfectly valid (non-subjunctive) usage would be something like *After dinner, we can go out and catch a movie. **If not that, then** we can go bowling, or whatever else you fancy doing.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I answer someone for example "if not that coat, then I'd not recognize you" is that correct?

No, it isn't.

The construction is

"If **it were** not **for** that coat, [then] I would not recognize you."

or, in the past tense:

"If **it had** not **been for** that coat, [then] I would not **have** recognized you." (Older version = **"Had it** not **been for** that coat, [then] I would not **have** recognized you.")

Both if clauses are in the subjunctive because he **is** in the coat and you **did** recognise him.

You cannot omit the bolded words. Words are omitted when there is a reasonable expectation of the listener being able to supply them.

It is possible to use "if not X then Y," but X and Y must be noun phrases:

A: "Take a coat. If not the green one, then the other." Note how the same omitted verb is provided (take) and is then omitted in the if clause.

Comment: In the valid uses of "if not X, then Y," they could also adjectives or adverbs; the point is that they can't be independent clauses, and as adjectival or adverbial phrases, must both modify the same thing. Examples: "The coat was, if not tattered, then at least very worn." "Run—if not quickly, then slowly, but run!"

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me! Yes, now it's logical for me.